# Prove that $ \partial f(E) \subseteq f(\partial E) $

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a $C^1$ function, and let $E \subset \Bbb R$ be a jordan measurable set. Prove:   $\; \partial f(E) \subseteq f(\partial E) $

Trying to prove it as part of another proof, been stuck for a while. Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true. Say $E=[-1,1]$ and $f(x)=x^2$. Then $\partial f(E)=\{0,1\}$ and $f(\partial E)=\{1\}$.

Comment: You are right. My original problem was to prove that if $E$ is jordan measurable, then $f(E)$ is jordan measurable. Any idea how to prove it?

Comment: That is an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You should accept this answer and ask a new one.